# Saving gensim LDA model to ONNX

Tags: gensim, lda, onnx

Is there a way to save a gensim LDA model to ONNX format?  We need to be able to train using Python/gensim and then operationalize it into an Onnx model to publish and use.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (March 2020, gensim-3.8.1) I don't know of any built-in support for ONNX formats in gensim.

Provided the ONNX format can represent LDA models well – & [here's an indiction it does](https://github.com/onnx/onnxmltools/blob/master/onnxmltools/convert/sparkml/docs/new_operators_ml.md#ai.onnx.ml.LDA) – it would be a plausible new feature.

You could add a feature request at the [gensim issue tracker](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues), but for the feature to be added, it would likely require a contribution from a skilled developer who needs the feature, & can write the code & test cases.